# Duplicate without user-selected canonical - OTHER version?

Tags: google-search-console, duplicate-content

In the Google Search Console report *"Duplicate without user-selected canonical"*, how do you find the duplicate URL of a particular URL? Going into "Inspect URL" doesn't seem to identify the location of the other (duplicate) file. I can find the duplicate only when the "Google-selected canonical" selects the other URL, but that doesn't always happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the source of the duplicate, you could Google a large part of the page content to find out wich page(s) are indexed with this particular content.

For a better result, you should put your query into brackets.

Plz provide more details (url for example) for a more detailed answer.

Comment: I'm removing the comment asking for a tool.  Requests for a tool make this question off-topic.  Such requests are not allowed here.

Comment: disagree. the tool would presumably be related to the topic; therefore, it wouldn't be "off-topic" as you assume.

Answer (score 0):

**Clear Answer:**
There is no way to find its easily.

You can just use external tools for detecting duplicate contents without 100% exact result or you can try it manually.